# How to give one pc with dhcp a default-gateway while the rest use static ip and static default-gateway

Tags: dhcp, lan

[image]

I have this topology where the PC0, Server0 and PC4 use static ip and static default-gateway, but one pc is Request DHCP, so i have to use DHCP ip address for him and static ip for the rest, now the problem is How to give him default-dateway so he can ping PC0 and Server0 vice versa.

Config:

```
Router
fa0/0 = 192.168.10.1/24
fa0/1 = 192.168.11.1/24

PC0(Static)
IP              = 192.168.10.123/24
default-gateway = 192.168.10.1

Server0(Static)
IP              = 192.168.10.111/24
default-gateway = 192.168.10.1

PC4(Static)
IP              = 192.168.11.123/24
default-gateway = 192.168.11.1

Router
DHCP pool nf0/0
Network 192.168.11.0 255.255.255.0

PC-PT(DHCP)
IP               = 192.168.11.2/24
Default-gateway  = Doesnt exist because i don't know how to config it
```

Comment: Which version of packet tracer are you using please?

Comment: @JeuneGuerrier i use 7.2

Comment: You need to include the full router configuration.

Comment: That the entire config of my router

Comment: No, it is not, the entire configurations is obtained by using the `show running-config` command and copying the result. What you have above is what you _say_ you configured, but we want to see what you _actually_ configured as reported by the router.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Network Engineering!  You can configure DHCP on the router for request-PC.  The default-gateway is the same as PC4: 192.168.11.1.  The difference is Request-PC gets the gateway address from DHCP, while PC4 has it statically configured.

Comment: Most of us here don't have packet tracer.  Please edit your question to include the full router config.  You can use the preformatted text option { }

Answer (score 0):

There are few things missing from your configuration

1. You need to exclude the default gateway from the pool of addresses you want to assign to your hosts
2. In your configuration, you need to set the default gateway to be assigned to each pool of address

You add the following configuration to the router.

```
! Move to Privileged mode
enable

! Global configuration mode
configure terminal

! Exclude the ip address of the default gateway
! from the pool of network
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.11.1

ip dhcp pool networkf0/1
! Set the default gateway for the hosts
! which will be using this pool of address
default-router 192.168.11.1
```

Once it is done, you need to disable and re-enable the DHCP option under the PC "Request DHCP".

And Done!